# How to delete every m-th and n-th line of a sequence of every K number of lines in a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Is there any way to delete every m-th and n-th line of a sequence of every `K` lines from a file using `sed` or `awk`?

Example:

```
cat input.txt
Aline1
Aline2
Aline3
Aline4
Aline5
Aline6
Aline7
Aline8
Aline9
Bline1
Bline2
Bline3
Bline4
Bline5
Bline6
Bline7
Bline8
Bline9
...
```

I want to remove every 3rd (line3) & 7th (line7) lines of a sequence of every 9 lines of the file.
So the output will look like

```
Aline1
Aline2
Aline4
Aline5
Aline6
Aline8
Aline9
Bline1
Bline2
Bline4
Bline5
Bline6
Bline8
Bline9
...
```

I tried  to combine two conditions at the same time but not successful:

`awk '(NR)%3 && (NR)%7' input.txt`

Edit:

---

Here 3rd and 7th lines refer to the lines in each of these sequences (`Aline*`,`Bline*` ...) which consist of 9 lines each.
So the first 9lines of the input file define sequence-A in which I want to remove the 3rd and 7th lines.
The next 9 lines of the input file define sequence B and there I want to do the same. So this would correspond to the 12th and 16th lines of the original file.

PS. I do not want to find by characters`*line3` & `*line7` and delete them since in general, these lines might contain anything.

Comment: Have you tried using `awk`, it can do the job easily for you.

Comment: I tried it but could not be able to combine two condition at the same time: `awk '(NR)%3 && (NR)%7' input.txt`

Comment: So, if I summarize, you don't want to filter the lines from their content. So no ```grep -v '[^0-9]3$' file.txt```

Comment: Yet, you want to filter 3rd and 7th line of several sequences of lines in your file. Here 3rd and 7th lines, but also 12th and 16th, since the second sequence starts at line 10

Comment: But we can't rely on line content itself to do that. I am missing something?
How are we suppose to guess that there are 2 sequences of 9 lines in your file, not 1 sequence of 18 lines or 3 sequences of 6 lines?

Comment: One way that I think to do it by splitting it into multiple files containing each sequences. FileA with Asequence with 9 lines, Bsequence in FileB with 9 lines and I can delete in each of these files 3rd and 7th lines and then combine at the end all such files. This would be the brute force way.

Comment: one problem with your deifnition is that you not only need to remove the 3rd and 7th lines, but you need to limit those replacements to every group of 9 lines; otherwise removing every 3rd line means you remove lines 3, 6, 9, 12, etc; while removing every 7th line means you remove lines 7, 14, 21, 28, etc

Comment: Yes you are correct. It’s 3rd and 7th line from each of these groups with 9lines.

Comment: You say "...using sed?". Do you REALLY only want a sed solution? Your awk attempt was pretty close.

Comment: WIsh you hadn't just deleted the line I added showing your attempt - the lack of an attempt in the question is what's causing you to get downvotes and close votes.

Comment: I accidentally deleted it while trying to improve the question. My bad.

Comment: you can always put it back.

Comment: What distinguishes the groups?  Is it based on some particular string in the first column?  Describe (completely) the difference between "Aline" and "Bline".  This is probably trivial, but you need to describe the problem accurately.

Comment: It’s purely based on every 9 lines in the file. I really do not want to distinguish by string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed '3~9d;7~9d' input_file
Aline1
Aline2
Aline4
Aline5
Aline6
Aline8
Aline9
Bline1
Bline2
Bline4
Bline5
Bline6
Bline8
Bline9
```

Answer (score 3):

A few `awk` ideas:

```
awk -v line1=3 -v line2=7 -v inc=9 '     # line1/line2 are line numbers to ignore; inc(rement) is added to line1/line2 for next set of lines to ignore
FNR==line1 { line1+=inc; next }          # skip line1, add "inc" for next line number
FNR==line2 { line2+=inc; next }          # skip line2, add "inc" for next line number
1' input.txt                             # print current line

# or 

awk -v line1=3 -v line2=7 -v blk=9 '
(FNR % blk == line1) || (FNR % blk == line2) {next}
1' input.txt

# or

awk -v line1=3 -v line2=7 -v blk=9 '
(FNR % blk != line1) && (FNR % blk != line2)
' input.txt

# or

awk -v line1=3 -v line2=7 -v blk=9 '
BEGIN { lines[line1]; lines[line2] }
! ((FNR % blk) in lines)
' input.txt
```

All generate:

```
Aline1
Aline2
Aline4
Aline5
Aline6
Aline8
Aline9
Bline1
Bline2
Bline4
Bline5
Bline6
Bline8
Bline9
```

Answer (score 3):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '(NR%9) !~ /^[37]$/' file
Aline1
Aline2
Aline4
Aline5
Aline6
Aline8
Aline9
Bline1
Bline2
Bline4
Bline5
Bline6
Bline8
Bline9
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is probably the shortest one-line answer :-)

Comment: @BabaYaga : i'm sure `awk '(NR%9+1)%4'` takes fewer bytes

Comment: I am very surprised how this really has a simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

use this combo modulo **`( ( NR % 9 ) % 4 ) < 3`** ::

```
mawk 'BEGIN { for(__=length(___="CBA"); __; __--) { 
                 for(_^=___; _!~!_; _++) { 
      
                    print substr(___,__,!!_)_ } } }' |
```

> ```
> {m,g}awk '($3 = ($2 = NR % 9 ) % 4 ) < 3'
> ```

```
A1 1 1
A2 2 2
A4 4 0
A5 5 1
A6 6 2
A8 8 0
A9 0 0
B1 1 1
B2 2 2
B4 4 0
B5 5 1
B6 6 2
B8 8 0
B9 0 0
C1 1 1
C2 2 2
C4 4 0
C5 5 1
C6 6 2
C8 8 0
C9 0 0
```

or better yet, simplify that to just either one of these :

- **`( ( NR % 9 ) + 1 ) % 4`**
- **`( ( NR + 1 ) % 9 ) % 4`**

most compact forms would be ::

> ```
> awk '(NR%9+1)%4'
> ```

> ```
> awk '(NR+1)%9%4'   # valid but not recommended
> ```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'x;s/^/x/;/^x{9}$/{s///;x;b};/^x{3}$|^x{7}$/{x;d};x' file
```

For each line in the file, swap to the hold space and insert an `x` at the start of the line.

If the line contains 9 `x`'s, reset the hold space, swap back to the pattern space and break out of any further processing i.e. print that line.

If the line contains 3 or 7 `x`'s, swap back to the pattern space and delete that line.

For all other line swap back to the pattern space and print the line as normal.

Of course this can more easily be done using GNU sed specific commands:

```
sed '3~9d,7~9d' file
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to extend your example with `Aline10` line if you want to see the results you displayed otherwise `Bline1` will be the 10th and not the 11th line as it is intuitive. So I created a file with `Aline1` up to `Aline20`.

With `sed` you can easily remove the nth line with this syntax

```bash
$ cat test.txt | sed '1~3d'
Aline2
Aline3
Aline5
Aline6
Aline8
...
```

But you cannot pipeline two seds as the original line numbers will be modified so this is wrong:

```bash
$ cat test.txt | sed '1~3d' | sed '1~7d'
Aline3
Aline5
Aline6
Aline8
Aline9
Aline11
Aline14
Aline15
Aline17
Aline18
```

However this is a piece of cake with awk

```bash
$ cat test.txt | awk '{ if (NR%3!=0&&NR%7!=0) printf "%s\n",$0 }'
Aline1
Aline2
Aline4
Aline5
Aline8
Aline10
Aline11
Aline13
Aline16
Aline17
Aline19
```

Comment: In my example, I have a sequence that repeats after every 9th line. This is what I tried to distinguish by `Aline`, `Bline`, etc. In each of these sequences, I want to remove the 3rd and seventh lines.

Comment: Only the 3rd and 7th or multiples?

Comment: I want to remove every 3rd and 7th from each of these sequences. That is why in the output from A-sequence, `Aline3, Aline7` are missing. Similarly from the B-sequence, `Bline3, Bline7` are missing. But I want to do it not by word matching but by deleting lines.

Comment: So in this example, it is actually the 3rd, 7th line for A-sequence, 12th, 16th for B-sequence... 21th, 25th for the next sequence.. and so on.

Comment: Usually `awk '{ if (NR%3!=0&&NR%7!=0) printf "%s\n",$0 }'` would be simplified to `awk '(NR%3) && (NR%7)'`